# get value from JSON string

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a object as shown below and i want to extract data from

```
stdClass Object
(
   [day1] => stdClass Object
     (
        [0] => 12.06.2015
        [part1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 19.00
                [1] => 22.00
            )

        [part2] => Array
            (
                [0] => 
                [1] => 
            )

    )
 )
```

How will i get date as shown above with key 0. I can get others as

$string->day1->part1[0]
   How can i get date  "12.06.2015" ? This seems to be complicated.

JSON string for reference

```
 {"day1":{"0":"12.06.2015","part1":["19.00","22.00"],"part2":["",""]},"day2":{"0":"13.06.2015","part1":["09.00","12.00"],"part2":["13.00","17.00"]}} 

used json_decode to decode it.
```

Comment: Can you post your JSON string too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
echo $string->day1->{0};
```

Or my preference, decode as an array with the second argument set to `true` in `json_decode()` to use this:

```
echo $string['day1'][0];
```